# issue with xib loaded in a Grect

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

learning much from you guys, and after a few hours I finally managed to load a xib into a GRect for a search xib that I built.

Basically, when you tap a cell in main.xib, it loads search.xib in a Grect so that I can filter down a list, click o nthe value, and place back into the cell in main.xib.

However I still have the cells from main.xib that overlay (tvcells) that overlay my search.xib.

Also it seems that none of the code is initializing for search.xib, I put an NSlog message in viewdidload in the search.xib, and nothing shows up in the console, letting me know that none of that code was executed.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

```
CGRect container = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
container.origin.x = 0;
container.origin.y = 0;

NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"ingredientSearchViewController" owner: self options: nil];
UIView *referencedView = (UIView *)[views objectAtIndex:0];

referencedView.frame = container;
[self.subView addSubview:referencedView];

NSLog(@"loaded subview but obviously not in subview xib");
```

Additional code that attempts to do this as a controller

```
if (self != nil){
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
if(self == nil){
     ingredientSearchViewController *vc = [[[ingredientSearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ingredientSearchViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    vc.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self.subView addSubview:vc.view];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is a method in NSViewController.

And you are creating a View from Nib, therefore you should use the equivalent method `awakeFromNib` for NSView.

Comment: Quest for my first view continues, thank you for the input.  I wrote some code with your suggestion (i believe), but it doesnt load the other controller.                                          if (self != nil){
  [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if(self == nil){
         ingredientSearchViewController *vc = [[[ingredientSearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ingredientSearchViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        vc.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
        vc.delegate = self;
        [self.subView addSubview:vc.view];
    }